# Using an input how do I copy certain data from a row on one sheet and display it in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

When I try this code an error comes up saying "Run Time Error '424': Object Required"
I can see that it finds the inputted number, but doesn't copy any number in the row. It also pastes "0" in the wrong sheet.
Here's my code:

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
x = InputBox(("Input palletizer pattern."), ("Pattern"), (0))
Application.Goto ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Palletizer 2").Range("A:A").Cells(Application.Match(x, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Palletizer 2").Range("A:A")))
With Selection
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = a
Set ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Palletizer Changeover App").Range("I6") = a
End With
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are a few issues with your code. For example the integer "a" is never set but it's used twice.

Comment: If you explain what you are trying to achieve, eg. what you need to copy to where, it will help a lot

Comment: You don't need that `Set` on the second to last line.

Comment: @jmdon I am looking to have a user input a certain value and given this value the code will find values in the same row and be able to take the values withing the row and display them in different locations.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you use a set statement to assign the integer `a` to the range `I6`. You can only use set statements to assign objects.

The error will go away if you remove the `Set` in the second last line. However, please note that it would be more obvious what you are trying to achieve if you explicitly assigned to the `Value` property of the range, which its default property.

With why the number does not appear at the right spot I cannot help you because your exact intentions are not clear to me from your question.